# Shader effect not applying after built to standalone

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

i'm applying a `shader` on a plane, it helps me cast shadow on a transparent planes (it makes the plane to be transparent as well).
the problem is that it is working in the scene mode and in the game mode as well when i am playing.
when i make a standalone version of it the effect is gone.

i set `Edit -> Project Settings -> Graphics` to include the shader.

and i also placed the shader in the resources folder.

what am i missing?
thanks!

[link to the shader](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j0br9pv5cl3h140/TranShadow.shader?dl=0)

Comment: What platform are you building for?

Comment: The platform is Windows

Comment: did you check your quality settings? Shadows could just be disabled there

Comment: i checked... and i got it now. the problem was that the shader works only with GPU. and that pc didnt have one.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

problem was that this `shader` requires a `GPU` and the laptop i used doesn't have.